# images inserted with utf-8 encoding do not render in the browser

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8

I'm inserting images into the database by setting encoding to utf-8 but when I'm retrieving in the browser it's coming up empty. However I can download it and open without any issue. Not sure how to fix it

Note: If i remove `setEncoding('utf8')` then the image renders correctly

while injesting

```
return db.documents.write({
    documents: {
    uri: common.issueURI(issue.id, issue.kind, true, attachments[file].name),
    contentType: attachments[file].mimetype,
    content: fs.createReadStream(attachments[file].path).setEncoding('utf8')
   },
}).result();
```

while reading

```
req.pipe(request.get(url).auth('admin', 'admin', false))
                    .on('error', function(err) {
                        log.error('ERROR', err);
                        handleConnRefused(err)
                    })
                    .on('response', function(response) {
                        res.setEncoding('utf8');
                        res.set('Content-Disposition', "inline; filename='" + attachmentName + "'");
                    })
                    .pipe(res)
```

Comment: Why are you encoding binary data as UTF-8? That's makes no sense.

Comment: Yes indeed. I'm not  familiar with the "when and hows" of encoding. After a little research I realized that encoding should be done only for text content and not for binary